# How to have multiple UITableViewCell prototypes in UITableView with protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, protocols

I have to use two different `UITableViewCell` in a `UITableView`, but these two cell has so much similarity. Let's cut to chase, here the example of my code right now:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if a {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstCell") as! FirstTableViewCell
        cell.config(withData: self.data[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondCell") as! SecondTableViewCell
        cell.config(withData: self.data[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

What I want is something like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: a.cellIdentifier) as! MyTableViewCellProtocol
    cell.config(withData: self.data[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

I know that this could be done with making a parent class then have `FirstTableViewCell` and `SecondTableViewCell` inherited from that parent class, but I want to achieve this by using `Protocol`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go..

```
class FirstTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, MyTableViewCellProtocol {
    func config(withData: Any) {

    }
}

class SecondTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, MyTableViewCellProtocol {
    func config(withData: Any) {

    }
}

protocol MyTableViewCellProtocol {
    func config(withData:Any)
}
```

And

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: a.cellIdentifier) as! MyTableViewCellProtocol
    cell.config(withData: self.data[indexPath.row])
    return cell as! UITableViewCell
}
```